# Croatian letters in CV

Tags: symbols, letters

I want to modify this CV

https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/professional-cv

with my data but I cant figure out how to write čćšđž letters. I usually copy 
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

and that usually works but when I add this to this CV it produces no erros only warning:
Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.

Can you help me write šđćčž.

This is example: (I didnt change much before \beginc{document} cause I wasn't sure what it does)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontspec}                   %for loading fonts
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip}   %other packages for formatting
\RequirePackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[big]{layaureo}              %better formatting of the A4 page
% an alternative to Layaureo can be ** \usepackage{fullpage} **
\usepackage{supertabular}               %for Grades
\usepackage{titlesec}                   %custom \section


%FONTS
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
%\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin}
%%% modified for Karol Kozioł for ShareLaTeX use
\setmainfont[
SmallCapsFont = Fontin-SmallCaps.otf,
BoldFont = Fontin-Bold.otf,
ItalicFont = Fontin-Italic.otf
]
{Fontin.otf}
%%%



%--------------------BEGIN DOCUMENT----------------------
\begin{document}

Ivafekoko\v{s}faekofea


\end{document}
```

It also comes with Fontin-Bold.otf, Fontin-Italic.otf, Fontin-SmallCaps.otf, Fontin.otf files.

Comment: You don't need to load `babel-croatian` if you don't use the language; you can simply input the letters as `\v{c}\'{c}\v{s}\dj\v{z}`. The message you're reporting is issued when you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and, in that case, you just use the accented letters.

Comment: I have tried that but it is not working. I know it usually works cause i remembered using it, but when i open the CV in the link in sharelatex and change some text to input those letters, they do not show. Can it be that the font don't have those letters? And thak you for response very much.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not registered in ShareLaTeX and don't intend to; can you prepare a minimal example to be shown here?

Comment: Yes, i edited question.

Comment: `Missing character: There is no š in font Fontin Regular`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem was font Fontin doesn't support Croatian letters. I tried one that I was sure supports (like Andada-Regular) and it worked. Thank you very much.

On the page https://www.fontsquirrel.com you can filter fonts by languages that they support and download them.